# color scheme for Ubuntu terminal from WSL-2 install

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, color-management

I'm using WSL-2 under Windows 10 which has installed Ubuntu 20.04.  The color scheme of the Ubuntu terminal has dark blue on a black background, which is unreadable.  How do I change that?

Comment: right click on WSL window top bar and choice properties, then go to change the colors there